# How to validate the text filed to enter Numbers

Tags: html

my requirement is to made html textfield  for mobilenumber to accept only numbers

For example If user enters '+'  symbol or alphabets then it should not allow him to enter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Html 5 in this case.

```
<input type="number" />
```

Otherwise, if you want to use Javascript to reach this you can take a look to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995183/how-to-allow-only-numeric-0-9-in-html-inputbox-using-jquery).

Comment: Thanks for the response I am using  Html 4.01 input type ="number" not working

Comment: In that case you must use Javascript/Jquery to achieve this. Check the question that I've posted.

Comment: Or you can use simple TexoTela plugin for it... Here is it

http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/numeric/

Write, if you have any questions.

Comment: I am using Extjs for validation if mobile number is empty i can show alert to user to enter the values as it is mandatory column like this

Comment: document.getElementById("snumber").value=snumber;

Comment: HAI CHUCK THIS CODE WORKS http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/index_famsupp_158.html